# How To Rebuild Huffman Tree From The Header?

Tags: algorithm, tree, compression, huffman-code

Is there anyway I can build Huffman Tree ? lets say I did a pre-order traversal on a Huffman Tree and each time I encounter a non-leaf node I append a '0' to my String and '1' if it is a leaf. Well lets say I got this String "0111" how can I use it to rebuild Huffman Tree the same structure it was ?

Comment: You can probably find some way to do it that way, but usually [canonical Huffman codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code) are used which is easier and smaller to encode in the header. By the way you don't need the tree for decoding anyway.

Comment: well I insist on building a tree I wanna try that approach and then traverse it to do the decoding process I know i have to use recursion but I don't know how to achieve it

Comment: You can't rebuild a Huffman tree from that.  You have nothing to indicate which symbol corresponds to each node.

Comment: oh yeah I guess you're right I just figured out well I'm trying to find a way to rebuild it the same it was